# What does this wildcard mean

Tags: wildcards

If `ls [ab]*` lists all files with names that start with a or b,
Then `ls [*a]*` will list all files with names that start with * (everything) or a. 
So why does it only list file with names starting with a?

Comment: Inside brackets, `*` loses its special meaning, so `[*a]` match `*` or `a`, not everything or `a`.